# Node.js, how to dynamic require files without losing intellisense code navigation

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio-code, node-modules

I'm working on a node.js application (discord bot).

I have several different files like events, models, services, etc. [Folder Structure.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b2J9X.png)

I'm facing the following problem: I need to require all files first thing, they need to be **easily** accessible from any file, and I also need to be able to use the **Code Preview** and **Go To Definition** Visual Studio Code tools.

This is my current approach:

```
const models = {};
const services = {};

const modelsFolder = 'models/folder/path';
const servicesFolder = 'services/folder/path';

const getFolderFiles = (folder, previousFolder) => {
  const tempMap = new Map();
  // Recursive search on all files inside the folder.
  // Returns a Map, where the filename will be the key,
  // and the require is the value.
  tempMap.set('fileName', require('found/file/path'));
  return tempMap;
};

// Method called from the index.js starting script.
const fetchAllFiles = () => {
  const modelsMap = getFolderFiles(modelsFolder);
  const servicesMap = getFolderFiles(servicesFolder);

  // Assign found Maps to the exportable Object.
};

module.exports = {
  fetchAllFiles,
  models,
  services,
};
```

After that, I can access anything that I want, be It a service or a specific model.

```
const { models, services } = require('holder/file/path');

const { ModelA, ModelB } = models;
const { MethodX1, MethodX2 } = services.ServiceX;
const { MethodY1, MethodY2 } = services.ServiceY;

// Do stuff...
```

The Problem: [No type definition found](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mpWGI.png), I really need to be able to peek at other files, since there are dozens of them.

I don't think this workflow is bad, but if there's a better one, I'd appreciate It!